# PySpark Unpacking tuple

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I did some Join operation and and am getting the result as bellow

```
[(u'20', (u'bbb', 4500)), (u'10', (u'aaa', 3500)), (u'30', (u'ccc', 7500))]
```

Now I need to convert this as bellow. How to do that

```
[(u'20', u'bbb', 4500), (u'10', u'aaa', 3500), (u'30', u'ccc', 7500)]
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @mtoto - Got the one which is expected., if you think some this is better than the one plse let me know.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> example = [(u'20', (u'bbb', 4500)), (u'10', (u'aaa', 3500)), (u'30', (u'ccc', 7500))]
>>> [tuple(x[:1]) + (x[1]) for x in example]
```

Result

```
[(u'20', u'bbb', 4500), (u'10', u'aaa', 3500), (u'30', u'ccc', 7500)]
```

Comment: That is not a PySpark solution, but plain Python. Don't you have an RDD after the join ? If yes, you should do this instead: ` rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1][0],x[1][1])).collect()`

Comment: @jaco - My bad . You are correct. I missed to mention that. 

before having [tuple(x[:1]) + (x[1]) for x in example]  , I did a collect() on my data.